# Waiting for a variable to be assigned before executing code in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to write a connection between React Native and Objective C to integrate a native view.

This mostly works at this point, however there's one final step I can't get working - passing back a generated code into React Native. I have the following code:

```
    RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

    RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(generateCode: (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {


     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"",
                                                               PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @""}];

        [self initzero];
        [self initone];
        [self getUserAuthorizationForProfileSharing];
    });
    callback(@[[NSNull null], self.code]);
}
```

Ultimate, the getUserAuthorizationForProfileSharing gets to this function:

```
- (void)sendProfileSharingAuthorizationToServer:(NSDictionary *)authorization {
   NSDictionary *response = [authorization objectForKey:@"response"];
   NSString *code = [response objectForKey:@"code"];
self.code = code;
}
```

This also works and correctly sets the code.

However as far as I can tell, this is all asynchronous. I'm wondering what method I would use to only issue the callback once I get the code property set on the object.

Is there any good way to do this?

EDIT: Here's the stack trace:

```
2020-05-18 12:24:29.930 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] NATIVE EXCEPTION
2020-05-18 12:24:29.930 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
(
    "4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00007fff50256e97 _ZSt11__terminatePFvvE + 8",
    "5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00007fff50256e39 _ZSt9terminatev + 41",
    "6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c12cd5c _dispatch_client_callout + 28",
    "7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c13ade6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1500",
    "8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4049 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9"
)
```

**EDIT: self.code is nil on execution, even when I put it into dispatch_async. I need to ONLY execute the callback AFTER an event has happened**

Comment: Simply move the `callback` invocation into your `dispatch_async`  block?

Comment: @Gereon No, same error. It's something about the value being nil. I'll put the stack trace above.

Comment: In that case, move the `callback` invocation to `sendProfileSharingAuthorizationToServer`

Comment: How? Doesn't React Native require the invocation be inside RCT_EXPORT_METHOD?

Comment: No. You can store the callback and invoke it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `code` only gets set `sendProfileSharingAuthorizationToServer` is called, you need to move the call to callback there as well:

```
- (void)sendProfileSharingAuthorizationToServer:(NSDictionary *)authorization {
   NSDictionary *response = [authorization objectForKey:@"response"];
   NSString *code = [response objectForKey:@"code"];
   self.code = code;
   callback(@[[NSNull null], self.code]); // do this only here
}
```

This will likely involve storing the callback somewhere, but that's fine as long as you make sure to only call it once (see https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios - "It's okay to store the callback and invoke it later.")

Comment: What type would I store the callback with?

Comment: Something like: @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RCTResponseSenderBlock *callback; ?

Comment: I guess so.. I have to admit that my ObjC is a little rusty and I've only done this in Swift so far.

Comment: Ultimately this is the type of variable to store the callback in. It all worked now.

@property(nonatomic, strong) RCTResponseSenderBlock callback;